# Laravel inertia mix migrate to vite error

Tags: laravel, vite, inertiajs

Error messsage: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined

```
module.exports = {
    methods: {
        /**
         * Translate the given key.
         */
        __(key, replace = {}) {
            let translation = this.$page.props.language[key]
                ? this.$page.props.language[key]
                : key

            Object.keys(replace).forEach(function (key) {
                translation = translation.replace(':' + key, replace[key])
            });

            return translation
        },
    },
}
```

I'm trying to switch from webmix to Vite. I define the file above with webmix like this, but when I define it in the same way with Vite, I get an error. How can I define it?

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp, Link, Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import Layout from "./Shared/Backendlayout";

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: async name => {
        let page = (await import(`./Pages/${name}`)).default;

        if (page.layout === undefined) {
            page.layout = Layout;
        }

        return page;
    },

    setup({ el, App, props, plugin}) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .component("Link", Link)
            .component("Head", Head)
            .mixin({ methods: { route } })
            .mixin(require('./base')) <------- THE DEFINITION HERE.
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#5671f0',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ESM, I reorganized my base.js file and imported it, then added it as a method within the mixing.

base.js;

```
import {usePage} from '@inertiajs/vue3'

export const __ = (key, replace = {}) => {
    let translation = usePage().props.language[key]
        ? usePage().props.language[key]
        : key

    Object.keys(replace).forEach(function (key) {
        translation = translation.replace(':' + key, replace[key])
    });

    return translation
}
```

app.js;

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp, Link, Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import Layout from "./Shared/Backendlayout";
import { __ }from "./base.js"

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: async name => {
        let page = (await import(`./Pages/${name}`)).default;

        if (page.layout === undefined) {
            page.layout = Layout;
        }

        return page;
    },

    setup({ el, App, props, plugin}) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .component("Link", Link)
            .component("Head", Head)
            .mixin({ methods: { route, __ } })
            //.mixin(require('./base')) <------- THE DEFINITION HERE.
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#5671f0',
    }
});
```